Transforming value into row number
I am conducting some survival analysis and an attempting to turn my wide table into long format for analysis using dplyR. I want to turn the value of 'dead flies' into rows with a binary status for this, for example:



Day
Sex
Dead(n)




1
Male
1


2
Male
2



into:



Day
Sample
Sex
Status




1
1
Male
1


2
2
Male
1


2
3
Male
1



I've tried some solutions using row_number() but honestly am drawing a blank.
Thank you for any help.

tidyr::uncount is what you’re looking for.

An approach using uncount
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  uncount(`Dead(n)`) %>% 
  mutate(Sample=row_number(), Status=1)
  Day  Sex Sample Status
1   1 Male      1      1
2   2 Male      2      1
3   2 Male      3      1

